# Why did Luke have his father's lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, luke-skywalker, the-last-jedi

Near the end of The Last Jedi,

> Luke uses some sort of astral projection to appear to the Resistance and face off with Kylo Ren.

During the scene, Luke is equipped with Anakin's old lightsaber. Given that

> Kylo would remember Luke with his green saber from ROTJ and Kylo had JUST witnessed Anakin's saber exploding,

why did Luke equip himself with that lightsaber instead of the one he'd been using for decades?

Comment: Luke didn't know it had been destroyed.

Comment: he was also banking on Ren's attachment to the saber to further goad him into anger